# In Magento2 file_get_contents any library

Tags: magento2

i am using file_get_contents in magento2 is there any framework or core function for this already in magento2?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the Interfaces available inside **`Magento\Framework`**.

For example, **Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface** gives you access to a **fileGetContents** function:

```
/**
 * Retrieve file contents from given path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param string|null $flag
 * @param resource|null $context
 * @return string
 * @throws FileSystemException
 */
public function fileGetContents($path, $flag = null, $context = null);
```

Which is implemented inside **`Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver`**

```
/**
 * Retrieve file contents from given path
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @param string|null $flag
 * @param resource|null $context
 * @return string
 * @throws FileSystemException
 */
public function fileGetContents($path, $flag = null, $context = null)
{
    clearstatcache();
    $result = @file_get_contents($this->getScheme() . $path, $flag, $context);
    if (false === $result) {
        throw new FileSystemException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                'Cannot read contents from file "%1" %2',
                [$path, $this->getWarningMessage()]
            )
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this work with URL?  I tried but no luck

Answer (score 0):

In case file located in your filesystem, use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver

In case you have to fetch file content from URL try Magento\Framework\HTTP\ClientInterface

```
$this->clientInterface->get($url);
$fileContent = $this->clientInterface->getBody();
```